# Bus Ticket Reservation System ( Simple code as .py file)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a code in a python file to do this:

i) Providing a bus ticket reservation function where a customer can buy bus ticket through the online system without a need to queue up at the counter to purchase a bus ticket.

ii) Enabling customers to check the availability and types of busses online. Customer can check the time departure for every bus through the system.

iii) Ability of customers to cancel their reservation.

iv) Admin user privileges in updating and cancelling payment, route and vehicle records.e following:

It does not need to be a web-based application. I only need to run the code in a python file. Could you please help me complete this?

## Bus class to manage seats

```
class Buses():
    def __init__(self, capacity):
        self.capacity = capacity
        self.passengers = []
    def addPassenger(self, name):
        if not self.open_seats():
            return False
        self.passengers.append(name)
        return True
    def open_seats(self):
        return self.capacity - len(self.passengers)
bus1 = Buses(18)
# make this a function that takes input that adds to seats
people = ["Bob", "Steve", "Ginny", "Bill"]
# Make a function for an admin to check seats and remove    
# Make this print out only the person being added. 
for person in people:
    success = bus1.addPassenger(person)
    if success:
        print(f"Added {person} to bus successfully.")
    else:
        print(f"No available seats for {person}")
```

Thanks a lot and I am looking forward to your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Change addPassenger to:

```
def addPassengers(self, passengers, verbose=False):
    if self.open_seats() < len(passengers):
        if verbose:
            for person in passengers:
                print(f"Added {person} to bus successfully.")
        return False
    self.passengers.extend(passengers)
    if verbose:
        print(f"No available seats for {person}")
    return True
```

Add admin functions:

```
def admin_remove(self, person):
    try:
        del self.passengers[person]
        print(f"Successfully canceled {person}'s reservation")
    except:
        print(f"Couldn't cancel {person}'s reservation: {person} has not reserved a seat")
```

^^^ was just an example... I did not get exactly what you meant by admin functions. However, it should be pretty easy to add more functions for admins based on what you want. I can help if necessary.

Finally, Stack Overflow is not a site where you ask other people to write your code for you. You can ask about errors in your code, information about syntax, etc., but try to refrain from asking others to write your code for you. I don't want to be mean and stop you from learning how to code, but just some advice for the future :).